Issues with nozzle temperature after a minor clog
First of all, pretty much noob, got a printer from a friend so my knowledge is quite low, so bare with me please.
I have Ender 3 V2, 4.2.2 motherboard with the mriscoc firmware. Everything worked pretty fine until I changed the capricorn tube instead of stock ptfe.
Apparently I havent mounted the tube so it sits properly with nozzle(my assmption) and after mounting I printed calibration cube. The cube turned out pretty ok. Next day when I booted up the printer, I noticed that nozzle wasnt heating up at all and dreaded thermal runaway kicked in, nozzle temperature too low.
I removed the heater block sleave and noticed some filament on the threads and heating block. Apparently removing the nozzle while cold never ends well, so after few tries, it actually heated up to the temperature that I was able to remove the nozzle. So it wasnt a huge blob type of clog, but clog nevertheless. Some filament was on the bottom of the heating block, and some around and possibly under the thermistor screw.
When I cleaned it up, I booted it up again without the nozzle but with sleave on and tried to heat it up again to clean the remaining of the filament. Again, the temperature went to 40 degrees and stopped there. After few tries, it skyrocket way above the set temperature on printer; set it to 180, switched off printer after it hit 198.
So my question is, is it thermistor? Heater seems to heat it up(those tries when it wasnt stuck at 40), but could it be the heater? Or is it something more serious? I heard from some googling that the filament on the heating block could cause the hotend mosfet on the motherboard can blow up.
Thanks in advance
